# Uploading current day's backup instead of all files via Cron jobs

Tags: bash, cron, ftp, centos, backup

I have a VPS running on Centos 7, and created a cron job to dump my database (Sql 8.0) and to create a `tar` to backup my entire site's files and this goes on everyday

I want to create another bash / cron job to connect to my backup server and upload those backup files stored on my VPS.
The problem is, I can't get it to upload only the newest files, not the entire files as there will be 7 backups every week.
I want it to only upload today's files, not all available files.
Should I use `rsync` ?
Here is my bash so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="ftp user"
PASSWORD="ftp password"
SERVER="IP or domain"
 
# local directory to pickup *.tar.gz file
FILE="/path/"
 
# remote server directory to upload backup
BACKUPDIR="/pro/backup/sql"
 
# login to remote server
ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
cd $BACKUPDIR
mput $FILE/*.tar.gz
quit
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find with `-ctime` to search for `.tar.gz` files changed in the last 7 days and then loop on the results, ftping each. Using this logic with your existing solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="ftp user"
PASSWORD="ftp password"
SERVER="IP or domain"

# local directory to pickup *.tar.gz file
FILE="/path/"

# remote server directory to upload backup
BACKUPDIR="/pro/backup/sql"

while read fil;
do 
  # login to remote server
  ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
  user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
  cd $BACKUPDIR
  mput "$FILE/$fil"
  quit
  EOF
done < "$(find $FILE -ctime -7 -name "*.tar.gz")"
```